# Print value of this address

Tags: c++, pointers, wchar

[image: code]

Hello. I have these lines of code in the image above. The second line prints the address. But I like to print the value of this address e.g. "Microsoft Loopback Adapter".

How to do that?

Comment: `PWCHAR` is a `short` pointer and not a `char` pointer. So `cout` does not treat it as a pointer to a null-terminated string, and prints the value of that pointer instead of the contents of the pointed string.

Comment: You're welcome. Good point in asking this question, and the answer below is also good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [std::wcout](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/wcout/):

```
std::wcout << description << std::endl;
```

`cout`  prints the pointer value of description as it does not treat `description` as a pointer to a null terminated string.

Comment: It's worth mentioning the difference between `PWCHAR` and `char*`, which yields the different behavior of `ofstream::operator>>` for each one of them.

Comment: Also note that char * use the current code page ie, pointer to an ANSI strings whereas WCHAR  APIs use UTF-16